# Does the GS1 MCS industry guideline use US patent 8228198?

Tags: patent-infringement

In March, 2012, all of the UHF Gen2 RFID chip manufacturers agreed to support Multi-vendor Chip-based Serialization (MCS), a voluntary implementation of a GS1 guideline for encoding 96-bit Serialized Global Trade Identification Numbers (SGTIN-96) into UHF Gen2 RFID tags. See:

http://www.rfidjournal.com/articles/view?9369

In June 2013, ADASA and Accelerate Ventures claimed that the GS1 guideline uses US 8,228,198. See:

http://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20130606005357/en/Accelerate-Ventures-ADASA-Join-Forces

Does MCS use 8228198?

Answer (score 0):

This second image provides additional reasons why MCS does not use US patent 8228198

[image: MCS does not provide uniqueness as required by the 198 patent]

Comment: Source of the image?

Answer (score -1):

The attached image explains why MCS does not use US patent 8228198

[image]

Comment: What is the source (link) of this screen shot?